# solving my Grid with sass?

Tags: layout, sass, grid-system

I have been trying to solve my grid and I'm not sure why my columns are not stacking up next to each other. when I am making a div with a container and inside it a row and then 12 columns the columns are taking the full width then staking below [image]

```
$screen-width: 1147px;
$number-of-columns: 12;
$gutter: 30px;
$column-width: $screen-width/$number-of-columns;
$padding: $gutter / 2;
$total-width: ($column-width * $number-of-columns) + ($gutter * ($number-of-columns - 1));
$gutter-width:($gutter / $total-width) * 100%;


@for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
  .column-#{$i} {
    width:  ( $i /$number-of-columns ) * 100%;
    background:#ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-left: $gutter;
  }
}



@mixin clearfix() {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
// Set Base Container
.container {
    max-width:$total-width;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 0 $padding 0 $padding;
    background: blue;
    @include clearfix;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  @include clearfix;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing the available space by the number of columns, but then you are adding a margin to the left of each column So if you have 10 columns then each column is 10% of the total width + gutters. This adds up to more than 100% and is pushing three of your columns onto the next line.

Most grid systems solve this in one of two ways...

A) use css calc() to calculate the width of each column by dividing the space by the number of columns then deducting the gutter. E.g. calc(10% - 30px);

B) Use padding on each column to create the gutters and add it equally on both sides. E.g. padding:0 15px; This will give you an even spread of the columns and require no calculations but the downside is you'll need -15px margin on each side of your container to accommodate it and you'll need an extra HTML tag inside each column.

Comment: shouldn't the   box-sizing: border-box;  put the gutter into consideration of the width ?

Comment: No, it means that the width of the box is calculated using the content, padding and border width, but not the margin.

Comment: @jonhbbs I used yr suggestion and added a function to calculate the width of each column, I thank you soo much.

Comment: No problem. If it solved the problem would you mind ticking it as the correct answer. An upvote wouldn't go amiss either ;-)

Comment: I sure will @jonhobbs

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to add that into a function, But now I have left margin what seems to be happening, which I'm not sure why is that, I have tried, things like putting a negative margin on the row.

```
 $screen-width: 2147px;
$number-of-columns: 12;
$gutter: 30px;
$column-width: $screen-width/$number-of-columns;
$padding: $gutter / 2;
$total-width: ($column-width * $number-of-columns) + ($gutter * ($number-of-columns - 1));
$gutter-width:($gutter / $total-width) * 100%;



@function grid-width($cols, $has-gutter:false) {
 @if $has-gutter {
   @return calc(((100% / #{$number-of-columns}) * #{$cols}) - #{$gutter}); 
 }
 @else {
   @return calc((100% / #{$number-of-columns}) * #{$cols});
 }
}

@for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
  .column-#{$i} {
    width: grid-width(#{$i}, true);
    background:#ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: $gutter;
    float: left;
  }
}



@mixin clearfix() {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
// Set Base Container
.container {
    max-width:$total-width;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height:100px;
    background: blue;
    @include clearfix;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  background: green;
  @include clearfix;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Alwan, you should probably have edited your original question instead of putting this new question as an answer, but in your .column you should have margin-left: $gutter/2; and margin-right:$gutter/2; to spread the gap evenly. Then, in .row you need to add margin-right: 0 - $gutter/2; and same for margin-left.

Comment: opps my bad !! but I went ahead and did that. it worked great with only the margin-left: $gutter/2; and margin-right:$gutter/2; on the .column, but once i added that to the .row it broke, I guess it wasn't needed.